# Why is this initial Kendo grid filter not working?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, filter, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I have a model like so:

```
Id    Type
-------------
1     Vehicle
2     Trailer
3     Vehicle
```

I am hoping to eventually use a radio button to control how this data is filtered on a Kendo grid, choosing to filter on whether `Type` equals `Vehicle` or `Trailer`.  I don't know how to do that, but, for now, I can't even get the initial filter to work.  My grid is as follows:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<PcKendoUi.Models.CompanyDueDatesIndexVM>()
    .Name("DueDates")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.Id);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Type);
    })
    .Filterable()
    .DataSource(ds => ds
        .Ajax()
        .Model(m => m.Id(x => x.Id))
        .Read(s => s.Action("Test", "CompanyDueDates"))
        .Filter(filter =>
        {
            filter.Add(f => f.Type == "Vehicle");
        })
     )
)
```

My code is based on the filter example from the [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/configuration#filter).

This still displays all 3 records in the model, rather than just rows `1` and `3`.  What is also interesting is that after specifying this initial filter, the filter controls also do not allow any filter.  That is, they are visible, I can type in data and click `Filter`, but it will not filter the grid.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the documentation your syntax is not correct, you wrote:

```
filter.Add(f => f.Type == "Vehicle");
```

When it should be:

```
filter.Add(f => f.Type).IsEqualTo("Vehicle");
```

Comment: Unbelievable.  My brain processed that as straight up LINQ.  Thanks a lot.